# How to create a GIT webhook to stop tags with specific name?

Tags: git, github, webhooks, alm

I am new to the world of GIT. I am looking for a way to create pre-receive webhook to stop pushing tags with name develop.

Or any webhook url which which checks for tags for every push event deletes tag with name "develop" should also work.

[image]

Comment: What git hosting site are you using? That screenshot doesn't look like GitHub.

Comment: To implement your own webhook, you'll need to set up a server that listens on a specific URL and responds depending on whether you want to allow the push to continue or not. What language are you planning to use?